# OfType() or is?

Tags: c#, linq

Let's say I have a collection `objs` of objects of different types, and I want to check whether there's at least one item with the specified type `MyType`. What solution is better?

Solution 1:

```
bool found = objs.OfType<MyType>().Any();
```

Solution 2:

```
bool found = objs.Any(o => o is MyType);
```

Is there any difference at all?

This question goes not only for Any() but for other LINQ methods, too.

Comment: "*Is there any difference at all?*" -- Not really, no. The latter is marginally cheaper since it avoids calling a method and allocating an object, but there's not much in it. If `objs` contained structs (and `MyType` was an interface, of course), then `OfType<T>` is expensive, since it boxes each element (it's an extension method on `IEnumerable`, not `IEnumerable<T>`)

Comment: related: https://ericlippert.com/2012/12/17/performance-rant/

Comment: https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#System.Core/System/Linq/Enumerable.cs,d25cf953c577dcd6

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Just for fun, I threw together a benchmark using [BenchmarkDotNet](https://benchmarkdotnet.org/):

```
public class MyType { }
public interface IMyType { }
public struct MyStruct { }

namespace Benchmark
{
    public class MyBenchmark
    {
        private readonly List<object> classes = new List<object>();
        private readonly List<MyStruct> structs = new List<MyStruct>();

        public MyBenchmark()
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++)
            {
                classes.Add(new object());
                structs.Add(new MyStruct());
            }
        }

        [Benchmark]
        public bool OfTypeClass()
        {
            return classes.OfType<MyType>().Any();
        }

        [Benchmark]
        public bool AnyClass()
        {
            return classes.Any(x => x is MyType);
        }

        [Benchmark]
        public bool OfTypeStruct()
        {
            return structs.OfType<IMyType>().Any();
        }

        [Benchmark]
        public bool AnyStruct()
        {
            return structs.Any(x => x is IMyType);
        }
    }

    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            var summary = BenchmarkRunner.Run<MyBenchmark>();
        }
    }
}
```

With the results:

```
BenchmarkDotNet=v0.11.5, OS=Windows 10.0.18363
Intel Core i7-8650U CPU 1.90GHz (Kaby Lake R), 1 CPU, 8 logical and 4 physical cores
.NET Core SDK=3.1.200-preview-014883
  [Host]     : .NET Core 3.0.0 (CoreCLR 4.700.19.46205, CoreFX 4.700.19.46214), 64bit RyuJIT
  DefaultJob : .NET Core 3.0.0 (CoreCLR 4.700.19.46205, CoreFX 4.700.19.46214), 64bit RyuJIT

|       Method |       Mean |    Error |   StdDev |
|------------- |-----------:|---------:|---------:|
|  OfTypeClass | 1,697.2 ns | 29.92 ns | 27.98 ns |
|     AnyClass | 1,477.2 ns | 18.77 ns | 14.65 ns |
| OfTypeStruct | 1,895.0 ns | 37.45 ns | 60.48 ns |
|    AnyStruct |   820.6 ns | 13.57 ns | 11.33 ns |
```

We can see that `Any` is slightly quicker than `OfType` (and `OfType` slightly more expensive for structs, as expected, because it needs to box them), but there's not much significant in it.

What's curious is that `AnyStruct` is so much quicker. I assume the JIT was able to spot that `MyStruct` doesn't implement `IMyType` and optimize things significantly.

Answer (score 5):

If we have a look at OfType() source code (https://github.com/microsoft/referencesource/blob/master/System.Core/System/Linq/Enumerable.cs), we can see

```
    public static IEnumerable<TResult> OfType<TResult>(this IEnumerable source) {
        if (source == null) throw Error.ArgumentNull("source");
        return OfTypeIterator<TResult>(source);
    }

    static IEnumerable<TResult> OfTypeIterator<TResult>(IEnumerable source) {
        foreach (object obj in source) {
            if (obj is TResult) yield return (TResult)obj;
        }
    }
```

So basically, they are the same.