# How to get all list items that match a specific interface?

Tags: c#, list, interface, type-conversion

I have a list of IThings:

```
public List<IThing> Things { get; }
```

which contains things that inherit from both IInterfaceA and IInterfaceB.

I want to make a new `List<IInterfaceA> NewList => GetItems();`

Where `GetItems()` should be doing similar to the following:

```
private List<IInterfaceA> GetItems()
{
    return Things.Where(el => el is IInterfaceA item);
   
}
```

I've tried doing this in multiple ways but can't figure out how to return a new list which in the process also converts the items, but only those that inherit from `IInterfaceA`.

Comment: You are looking for `OfType<>` : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.oftype?view=net-5.0

Comment: See `.OfType<IInterfaceA>()` Also [OfType or is](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60722644/oftype-or-is)